# P value significance in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, p-value

I understand that this p value: < 2e-16 is significant
But is this p value: 1.4e-05 significant? 
I'm not sure how you can tell / what the 'e' means.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=2e-16 for more answers.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630322/what-is-the-e-notation-regarding-to-decimal-numbers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation